# Is it possible to accessing Python files from other local cloned repos with "Enable IntelliSense for custom package locations"

Tags: python, python-import, reusability

New to Python, I thought it would be nice to get everyone reuse each others Python Code but accessing Python Code in another Folder, whick could in this case be a local cloned Git repo with name for example python-utilities. Is "Enable IntelliSense for custom package locations" a way to do this. Normaly it is easy to access local python files with import , but is difficult då resuse this often useful codes in other work.

The question is also really what the best approach to share good code within an organisation. Creating package locally?

I want to share and access common python files in other work. Normally our code exist in different Git repos